# Google Maps for Android. Failed to load map. Could not contact Google servers

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to work with Google Maps on my Android but where it should appear the map is white and I get the error: Failed to load map. Error contacting google servers. 
I've followed many tutorials and all the answers related on that problem but I still can't fix it. I think I have the correct API key (Google Maps for Android) and permissions, but perhaps I forget something and somebody could help me. My Android version is 4.1.1. Thanks a lot.

The AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.mapmap"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.mapmap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="KEY_FROM_GOOGLE_CONSOLE"/>
            <activity
                android:name="com.example.mapmap.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

The activity_main.xml:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

The MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.mapmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
  com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
```

instead of

```
  com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
```

Comment: Put your key here                          android:value="KEY_FROM_GOOGLE_CONSOLE" if u forgot